# setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. where is the culprit?

Tags: react-native

I got this warning.

Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

How do I know which setState is throwing it? I put a log in front of all setState and none is being print.
There should be a better method?
I suspect it's coming from a callback or listener somewhere.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The yellow error box will tell you which component attempted to call setState

Comment: Maybe you can share some code.

Comment: Probably you called this.setState() method in componentWillMount() method which is called before initial rendering occurs. So, render method did never work even once before you called setState().

Comment: @FuzzyTree Oh yes you are right the error message points to a component. Thanks a lot! my bad.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
console.log(this.state.WHATYOUNEED)
```